# How To Stop RDS Users from download the Database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have some AWS RDS and for some reasons I want to create RDS users that only read and also can NOT download the whole Database.
Is there anyway for it?
thank you all so much

Comment: Don't let them connect directly to the database.

Comment: If you can explain the _specific_ threat that you're trying to avoid, there may be other solutions (such as views). But in general, if you give someone permission to select from a table, they will be able to download all the data that they can access.

Comment: I see, thank you. All the data is needed to be secret, but surely some Devs must access to develop the features. We just don't want them to download it

Comment: Create a development database that doesn't have real data in it.